# $x^2 f^{''}(x)+4xf^{'}(x)+2f(x)\geq 0$, prove $f(x)\leq 0$

Tags: analysis

More specifically, suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $x^2f^{\prime \prime}(x)+4xf^{\prime}(x)+2f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in (a,b)$. Prove that $f(x)\leq 0$ for $x\in [a,b]$.

I'm not sure how to approach this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solution will be of the form $x^n$ so you could try to substitute it in and get the result for $f(x)$ but I guess there's another way...

Comment: @user88595 There are many other solutions besides $x^n$.....

Answer (score 10):

*Hint:* $\left(x^2 f(x)\right)'' \ge 0$ means $x^2 f(x)$ is convex.